# Where to find a high-quality reversed map of the world?

Tags: maps

I'm looking for a high-quality (probably vector) [reversed map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversed_map) of the world (with the South up), so I can display it in my office and place pins in places where our group members have traveled (for work!).

I would either buy a poster and have it shipped, or find a high-quality map to download and get it printed in poster size locally.

Comment: Maybe it is better to post your question in this section: http://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Ale I thought about it, but GIS is more about development/building of maps, so it seemed more appropriate here (where I can find fellow users of maps)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about buying funny maps and not about travelling.

Comment: I wonder if this question might be suitable for the [opendata beta site](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/) since you're looking for vector data? They have a "maps" tag.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can find in Google this is the [best google Images search provides](https://www.google.nl/search?q=high%20resolution%20reversed%20world%20map&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=GmhqUqvVFYfM0QX2iIGIBg&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1057&bih=626#q=upside%20down%20world%20map&tbm=isch&tbs=isz%3alt,islt:8mp&facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=GgcmIZahVGn_7M%3a;m3-8MwfezV7szM;http%253A%252F%252Fpaulmencke.nl.dualdev.com%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2010%252F10%252FUpside-down-World-Map.jpg;http%253A%252F%252Fpaulmencke.nl.dualdev.com%252F%253Fpaged%253D2;3508;2480):

[Click to check the search I did for reversed maps > 8MP](https://www.google.nl/search?q=high%20resolution%20reversed%20world%20map&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=GmhqUqvVFYfM0QX2iIGIBg&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1057&bih=626#q=upside%20down%20world%20map&tbm=isch&tbs=isz%3alt,islt:8mp&imgdii=_) Maybe there are other maps that suit best what you want.

I didn't find anything over 10MP.